# React/Redux: Global function that can dispatch actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am looking to implement a React/Redux function as a global utility that has the ability to dispatch actions.

This is *not* a Component/Container.  Simply a global/static function that can be imported and invoked by others.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance for any ideas/suggestions you can provide!

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly you are trying to do? Typically you try to avoid using global references of any kind. This is why Redux provides dispatch to components as an argument.

Comment: The idea is to have an application-level error modal that can be invoked from any point.

Expecting to have a utility method that only receives the error message to be displayed and then dispatches (on behalf of any caller) the action to open the error modal.

Answer (score 34):

The `dispatch` comes from the `Store` so you just need a global reference to your `Store`.

So suppose your application root looks something like this:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store} /> ...);
```

Just export that `store`:

```
export const store = createStore(root);
```

And from your static util import the store:

```
import {store} from "../path/to/app/root";

store.dispatch({ ... });
```

---

A better way to do this would be to make your util function accept `dispatch` as an argument, this way you have no global references to `store`.

Comment: It seems strange that a utility method would need dispatch ... dispatch is usually called in an async "thunk" style action creator - see about 2/3 through this page - http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html.

I would think any truly "static" helper would be pure and simply return whatever is needed to be dispatched in an action.

Comment: I agree, even though this is doable it's probably an anti-pattern.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!   Being somewhat of a Redux/React newbie I wasn't aware you could export the store in this manner.
Thanks!

Comment: Anti-pattern or not, this helped me work around some buggy libraries that my co-worker has been struggling with for over a day now, the alternative to which would be to write my own monolithic monstrosity.

Comment: Is the global reference to store wrong thing? Btw, I only export dispatch from my store.

Comment: @Qwerty I wouldn't call it wrong (some might), only that global references are to be avoided in general (use dependency injection, etc). In this case I'd say not a lot of harm can come of it, though. Chances are your unit test framework can still mock it if need be.

Comment: Ironically "global patterns are to be avoided..." which is exactly what redux is. A global way to reference data. This solution is practical.

Comment: if you add dispatch as a parameter - you will have to pass it everytime. Even if you need it only in one function you have to add parameter to all functions in the call tree... 100? 1000?

Comment: Can you give a code example on your last thought "A better way to do this would be to make your util function accept dispatch as an argument, this way you have no global references to store"

Answer (score 5):

I'm old school; in app.js I would just do:

```
window.store = store
```

That's it - store exposed globally, no need to import etc. This will break server side rendering, but that breaks if you use a global dispatch in any case. See this twitter thread: https://twitter.com/Grynn/status/955485816389685248

Quoting reply from Dan Abramov (in above thread):

> Makes testing harder, breaks if there are several such apps in the
>   page (which happens in practice in big products), makes server
>   rendering impossible. Otherwise it's fine sure